# Select a subdiv with JS event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple buzzfeed quiz with HTML and JavaScript as a practice project. All my options are divs of subdivs in HTML. The four options are a div, the top row of two options is a subdiv, and then each option is a subdiv under that. So my HTML looks like:

```html
<div id="q1">
  <p class="question">What's your favorite kind of bread?</p>
  <!-- First set of options -->
  <div class="optionsSet">
    <!-- Sourdough -->
    <div class="option" id="sourdough">
      <img class="optionPic" src="/pictures/b-sour.jpg" alt="Sourdough" id="sourpic">
      <p class="caption">Sourdough</p>
    </div>
```

I can't get my JS event listener to grab onto anything. Instead it executes immediately upon loading the page no matter which event I'm trying to hone in on. Here's the latest that I think should be foolproof but it's not working:

```js
var test = new function test() {
  console.log("test succeeded");
}

document.getElementById('sourdough').addEventListener("mouseup", test)
```

Once I get this formatted and able to produce an output predictably and reliably I'll tinker with the actual outputs. For no,w I can't even get to that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = new function test() {
  console.log("test succeeded");
}
```

You need to remove the `new` keyword before the function declaration.
`new` is used when you want to create a new object

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nm557plrm?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&view=editor).

Comment: That was it, huh? I tried it about 10 different ways and couldn't get it. Took new out and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "new" from your code and it should be fine.